# How to programatically update index.html before it is fed to mainWindow.loadURL?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Trying to set `data-color-scheme` attribute to match `nativeTheme` theme to fix an issue whereby text color defaults to black triggering a transition when `prefers-color-scheme: dark` sets color to white.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-scheme="auto">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you require `data-color-scheme` to be set / updated on application start or by the user mid-application?

Comment: @midnight-coding Both, but asking here in the context of application start.

Comment: On application start you need to take into account two cases. 1: The application has never been run before so detect the preferred OS colour scheme, set it in your application settings (file) and then set it in your HTML render. 2: Load application settings (file) and set colour scheme via IPC in your HTML. Are you using a storage system such as a JSON file to keep your application settings in? I will be able to draw up a quick example if you like.